How do I configure Python "black" to sensibly format Polars?
How do I configure Black to sensibly auto-format Python code for the Polars library?
With the default settings, it likes to left-align .select/.with_columns calls with many arguments. I want the following code to not get mangled. Is there a standard configuration?
import polars as pl

df = df.select(
    user_ids=pl.col("log_entry").str.extract(r"User ID: \[([\d ,]+)\]"),
    session_times=pl.col("log_entry").str.extract(
        r"Session Time: \[([\d :]+)\]"
    ),
    event_type=pl.col("log_entry")
    .str.extract(r"Event Type: ([\w ]+)")
    .cast(pl.Utf8),
    event_duration=pl.col("log_entry")
    .str.extract(r"Duration: (\d+)")
    .cast(pl.Int32),
)


This is roughly how I think it should be formatted, if wrapping at 79 chars:
df = df.select(
    user_ids=pl.col("log_entry").str.extract(
        r"User ID: \[([\d ,]+)\]"
    ),
    session_times=pl.col("log_entry").str.extract(
        r"Session Time: \[([\d :]+)\]"
    ),
    event_type=pl.col("log_entry")
        .str.extract(r"Event Type: ([\w ]+)")
        .cast(pl.Utf8),
    event_duration=pl.col("log_entry")
        .str.extract(r"Duration: (\d+)")
        .cast(pl.Int32),
)


Black is not about how you think code should be formatted, it is about how black thinks code should be formatted.

Black is not about any type of configurability - if you need formatting modification (which some domains absolutely do!), enclose your formatted code in # fmt: off...# fmt: on directives or use YAPF.
